# RecognitionListener onBeginningOfSpeech does not trigger sometimes

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I'm using RecognitionListener for my speech to text app.  I have a simple button that has onClickListener which calls `mRecognizer.startListening(mIntent);` when the user presses the button.

I notice that if a user presses the button and speaks at the same time, the onBegginingOfSpeech only triggers after the user stops speaking. Basically this is the sequence of event:

1. User press button and speak at the same time.
2. onReadyForSpeech called.
3. User pause/stop speaking.
4. User speaks again.
5. onBeginningOfSpeech called.
6. User stops speaking.
7. onResults called.

I also noticed that the data returned from onResults includes the message the user spoke in 1.  Is there a way to trigger the onBeginningOfSpeech after step 2?

**EDIT:** What I need is for onResults to trigger after step 3 since the user stops speaking.  I asked about the onBeginningOfSpeech trigger because I think onResult can't be triggered unless the onBeginningOfSpeech is triggered first.

Comment: Do you mean not include in "includes the message the user spoke"?